# If I make my login page use 'https' in Spring, how do I avoid Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, https

The homepage for my Spring MVC 3.0 app is:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

If I make the login page use HTTPS:

```
https://localhost:8443/login
```

I get this error when I try to navigate to the login page:

```
Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): Unknown error.
```

**What's the correct way to configure my Spring app so that this doesn't happen?**

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the server is listening to port 8443? You check this wit following command

```
netstat
```

what results in a list of active connections

```
Proto Local adres Externnal adres Status
```

TCP PC04566:1040 localhost:1041 ESTABLISHED